# Hierarchical logistic regression

Tags: r, binary, regression, glm, hierarchical

I am trying to predict depression by using two quantitative variables and their interaction. However, before I want to see how much variance they explain, I want to control for a few variables.

My plan was to build a logistic regression model:

Depression = Covariates + IV1 + IV2 + IV1:IV2

Unfortunately, R doesn't seem to care about the order in which you add the variables to the model (Type III sum of squares?). Is there a way to build a logistic regression model in which the order does matter?

Thanks in advance!
-Lukas

Comment: You can always compare the full and reduced models...

Comment: You can regress the response on the covariates only and then re-run the regression using `depression ~ IVs + offset(b1 * covariate1 + ... + bn * covariaten)` where b1, ..., bn are the coefficients from the first regression.

Comment: That's a great way around it, thanks a lot! The intercept from the first regression does not have to be included?

Comment: Either way would work but the interpretation of the intercept you get from the second model changes.  if you include the intercept from the first model then the intercept from the second model is the difference between the overall intercept and the intercept from the first model; otherwise, the intercept you get out from the second model is the overall intercept.